# why F4 can't make javascript run properly?

Tags: vim

I have the following in my `_vimrc` (Windows XP+gvim):

```
:cd c:/workspace
:nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent  !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"'shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)<CR>
```

I open gvim and paste the following into a file which has no file name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<body>    

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>    
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>    
<p id="demo"></p>    

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>    

<script>    
function myFunction()    
{    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();    
}    
</script>    

</body>    
</html>
```

When press <kbd>F4</kbd> I find that Firefox can't properly get my current file as seen in the image.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect? If you haven't given your document a filename, it can't be written out to a file for firefox to load...

Comment: `%:p` in `shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)`  will get the current name,and firefox will load it.

Comment: as you just said, "into a file which has no filename". vim won't create one for you.

Comment: dear romainl ,both of them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you paste your code into vim it exists only in memory. Until you save that code to a file the code does not exist on the filesystem. Firefox has the capability to open local HTML files, but it cannot read from vim's memory. Thus, you need to first save the file before you can open it in Firefox. For example:

```
:w temp.html<Enter><F4>
```